# divisibility of $\sum _{r=1}^{n} r^5$ by $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

if $$S_5=\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^5$$ and $$S_3=\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^3$$For what values of $n$ the sum $S_5$ is divisible by $S_3$.

One way of approach is finding the sum $S_5$ using method of differences and finally we get a polynomial with degree $6$. As we know $$S_3=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$$ We can find general value of $n$ just by dividing $6th$ degree polynomial by $4th$ degree polynomial.  But this is very lengthy method. I will be happy if any one has better approach

Comment: Do you mean getting integers or they having just a common multiple

Comment: no getting integers

Comment: See [Summae Potestatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Reconstruction_of_.22Summae_Potestatum.22). and [Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#/media/File:JakobBernoulliSummaePotestatum.png).

Answer (score 6):

You can show by induction that $S_3 = \dfrac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2$ and $S_5 = \dfrac{1}{12}n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{S_5}{S_3} = \dfrac{2n^2+2n-1}{3}$. This is an integer iff $2n^2+2n-1$ is divisible by $3$.

So you just need to determine the values of $n$ such that $2n^2+2n-1 \equiv 0\pmod{3}$.

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $2n^2+2n-1 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then $2n^2+2n-1 \equiv 0\pmod{3}$.

If $n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then $2n^2+2n-1 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Therefore, $S_5$ is divisible by $S_3$ iff $n \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: $$3\mid(2n^2+2n-1)\iff3|(n^2+n+1)$$   $$n^2+n+1\equiv(n-1)(n+2)\pmod3$$  But $$n-1\equiv n+2\pmod3$$  So, we need $$n-1\equiv0\iff n+2\equiv0\pmod3$$